# How to mock knex promise using jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs, knex.js

I am trying to mock a knex call, however, I am not able to mock all the promise tree.
My mock follows:

```
jest.mock('../src/db/Client', () => {
  const mKnex = {
    select: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    then: jest.fn((done) => done([list with my data])),
    catch: jest.fn(),
  };
  return jest.fn(() => mKnex);
});
```

I was able to mock the `select` and `then`, but jest complains that `catch` is not a function, and I am running out of ideas on how to mock it and make my test pass.
[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: `select` returns a promise, why not [`mockResolvedValue`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue)?

Answer (score 1):

Like @jonrsharpe said, you don't need to mock the `then` and `catch` method.

If you want to test the successful scenario, you should use [mockResolvedValue](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue) method like this: `db.select.mockResolvedValue(mResponse)`, `then` method will be executed.

If you want to test the failure scenario, you should use [mockRejectedValue](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockrejectedvaluevalue) method like this: `db.select. mockRejectedValue(mError)`, `catch` method will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

```
jest.mock('../src/db/Client', () => {
  const mKnex = {
     select: jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce([{ key: 'blabla' }]).mockReturnThis(),
     catch: jest.fn(),
  };
  return jest.fn(() => mKnex);
});
```

Changing your code to this can fix the catch problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`knex-mock-client`](https://github.com/felixmosh/knex-mock-client) in order to mock your DB in tests environment.

```js
import { getTracker } from 'knex-mock-client';

jest.mock('../src/db/Client', () => {
  const realKnex= require('knex');
  const { MockClient } = require('knex-mock-client');

  const mockedKnex = realKnex({
    client: MockClient,
  });
  return { db: mockedKnex };
});

it('should query activities', async () => {
  const trackId = 124;
  tracker.on
    .select(
      (rawQuery) => rawQuery.sql.include('activities_table') && rawQuery.bindings.includes(trackId)
    )
    .responseOnce([{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]);

  const results = await GetActivities({ trackId });

  expect(results).toHaveLength(2);
});
```

For more details checkout: https://github.com/felixmosh/knex-mock-client.

Full disclosure, I'm the author of the lib.